# How to use InjectMocks if the instance to be injected has a final class

Tags: java, mockito, cdi, logback

I want to test some services with mockito. The services are based on CDI and, unfortunately, use field injection, which I can't change.

```
public class Service {
   @Inject Logger logger;

   public void method() {
      logger.info("some log text");
  }
}
```

Now it is quite easy to create the testable instances with mockito's `@InjectMocks` annotation. It will inject either mocks and spies.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest {
  @Spy Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Service.class);

  @InjectMocks Service service;

  @Test public void test() {
     // Given
     // When
     service.method();
     // Then
  }
```

I need some working logger injected into my service class under test. The logger framework is slf4j, the preferred logger is logback. But unfortunately again, logback's implementation of `Logger` is final, so I can't spy on that, it results in a runtime exception.

Workarounds, that come to my mind:

- use reflection to initialize the logger attribute on the service (poor man's injection)
- implement a spyable (non-final) logger wrapper that delegates to the final logback logger

But is there a clean or at least better solution for that (those) problem(s)?

Comment: Have you considered incorporating [Weld SE](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#d0e5727) into your testing infrastructure?

Comment: @SteveC - yes. But with true CDI injecting mocks is really aweful (I miss guice on the project). I use arquillian for integration tests without mocks.

Answer (score 2):

Your class under test is most likely using Logback incorrectly. Instead of declaring the `logger` field as being of type `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger`, it should be the interface type `org.slf4j.Logger`, which is implemented by the final Logback logger class.

That way, you avoid the issue since there is no `final` class to be mocked or injected.

Comment: to add to this... When mocking a class that implements an interface. It's always best to mock the interface, because of the answer right here. And also if your mocking the class you don't care about the implementation anyway.

Comment: Yes .. but .. as I said, I don't want to mock the interface, this time, because I want to read the logger statements from the class under test on the console. Sure, it's some special case and on fully automated tests I don't really care, but I want that during development.

Comment: Ah, btw., the declared type is `org.slf4j.Logger`. The factory returns the logback implementation. And that class is final so Spy is unhappy.

Comment: Oh, I see, it's an `@Spy`, not a `@Mock`... In this case, the best solution is your first workaround, setting the field with a real object through Reflection. The only other viable alternative would be to use a mocking tool supporting `final` classes, such as PowerMock.